# Trying to get python RegExp to remove everything between brackets [ abc ]

Tags: python, regex

This regexp removes everything between the $ $, but not the [ ]

```
r"([$@*[\]()&?]).*?(.)"
```

I think it's something to do with the [ and the ] not being the same character but I'm not exactly sure what's going wrong. Any ideas on how to deal with removing everything between and including these special characters [ ]?

[image]

https://regex101.com/r/pK9gX3/96

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex doesn't work because in the second case `\1` is trying to match a `[`. One way around this is to call out each option separately:

```
(\$[^$]*\$|\[[^]]*\])(.*)
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pK9gX3/97)

Note that doing it this way you can make the first group non-capturing and change your replacement to `\1`.

Answer (score 1):

If you have more one surrounding characters like `{}, (), [] .. etc` try this code:

```
import re
# list of surrounding characters to build a large regular expression 
surrounding = [('\$', '\$'), ('\[', '\]'), ('{', '}')]
text = """
$remove$text
[remove]text
"""

RE_PATTERN = '|'.join(r'{0}[^{0}]*?{1}.*?'.format(*s) for s in surrounding)
print(RE_PATTERN)  # \$[^\$]*?\$.*?|\[[^\[]*?\].*?|{[^{]*?}.*?
print(re.sub(RE_PATTERN,'', text))
# text
# text
```